# Convert my columns in to rows in postgresql without creating any extensions

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a data result from a view like below,

[image: Current view]

But I want a view like this

[image: Need a view from the original view]

Can any one help me to do this via postgresql without using extensions.

Comment: Please go through all the questions for [pivot or crosstab](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29+%5Bpostgresql%5D)

Comment: This is typically much better done in the application, than in SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use aggregation

```
select project, max(case when role='owner' then name end) as owner,
 max(case when role='client' then name end) as client,
 max(case when role='Team' then name end) as Team
from table 
group by project;
```

Alternatively you can use the `filter()` clause which makes this a bit easier to read:

```
select project, 
       max(name) filter (where role='owner') as owner,
       max(name) filter (where role='client') as client,
       max(name) filter (where role='Team') as Team
from table 
group by project;
```